# Про toolbar, штору и всякое

Tags: android, android-studio, android-navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

Делаю приложение с одной активностью, остальное будет в фрагментах, приложение для такси. На главном экране висит карта, боковая шторка есть, но вызывается по FloatingActionButton. На шторке есть меню, по которому вызываются соответствующие фрагменты.

Вопросы такие:

нужно чтобы в каждом фрагменте была кнопка Up, то есть можно было вернутся обратно к карте. Как это лучше сделать? Сделать toolbar, а на нем кнопку?

Хочу избавится или скрыть FAB когда она не нужно, а то висит постоянно поверх всего, в том числе фрагментов.

Посоветуйте как лучше реализовать кнопку вызова боковой шторки, через toolbar? Но как от toolbar оставить только кнопку, чтобы он не перекрывал карту.

Comment: стандартный Navigation Drawer Activity уже все поддерживает, вам осталось только убрать fab. Activity построена на новой библиотеке Navigation (раньше было через getSupportFragmentManager вроде)

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: А как сделать чтобы тулбар с кнопкой вверх был виден только в фрагментах, но не на карте. Рисовать отдельный виджет на каждом фрагменте?

Comment: Reutckiy а у вас карта во фрагменте находится?

Comment: @danilshik нет, карта находится в отделенной разметке contentmain

Comment: @Valeriy Reutskiy можно кнопку вверх прятать в определенном фрагменте.

Comment: @Романыч так мне надо чтобы тулбар был только на фрагментах, а на главной активности где карте его не должно быть

Comment: В шаблоне Nav Drawer тулбар привязан к активности. Я так понимаю можно написать интерфейс, в котором прятать его в зависимости от фрагментов. Или наоборот показывать там где нужно, Или сделать тему без тулбара и пихать его отдельно во фрагменты. Оба случая кажуться дичайшим костылем))) Хотя не факт

Comment: Можно попробовать шаблон с кнопками нижней навигации - bottom navigation. Там тема с тулбаром прокатит

Comment: Т.е.верхний тулбар убрать вообще, а добавить кнопки внизу, и кнопку Up в том числе?